# Why a basic loop isn't accelerated by OpenMP?

Tags: c++, g++, openmp

I have a basic loop:

```
int i, n=50000000;
for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    register float val = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
}
```

That I want to accelerate with OpenMP. I previously set:

```
omp_set_dynamic(0);
omp_set_num_threads(nths);
```

with `nths=4`

And the final loop is:

```
int i, n=50000000;
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(n) default(shared)
for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    register float val = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
}
```

The non parallelized loop takes 1.12s to execute and the parallel one takes 21.04s (it can varies a lot depending on my linux priority process). I am on a x86 platform with Ubuntu and 4 CPUs with 1 thread each. I compile with `g++` (I need it) that I flagged with `-fopenmp` and I use the library `-lgomp`

Why OpenMP doesn't accelerate this basic loop ?

**EDIT:**

Regarding the answers I changed the inside of the loop to be:

```
for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    a[i]=i;
    b[i]=i;
    c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
}
```

with `n=500000` and the pragma:

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(n) default(shared) schedule(dynamic) num_threads(4)
```

I also changed the code to use only `gcc` and I have the same problem:

```
With 1 Thread
Test        ms = 0.003000
Test Omp    ms = 19.695000
With 4 Threads
Test        ms = 0.003000
Test Omp    ms = 240.990000
```

**EDIT2:**

I changed the way I was measuring time when using OpenMP. Instead of the `clock()` function I used the `omp_get_wtime()` one, the results are way better.

Comment: Well maybe it's too basic to be accelerated by launching many threads, which has a cost.

Comment: I thought about that but I have other functions that consist of converting RGB images to grayscale using both OpenCV and C. None of them is accelerated so I thought I had a problem with my OpenMP usage with C++ (I only used it with gcc before). And I am not at work anymore so I cannot check it with gcc...

Comment: First, there is a data race in your code that uses the same PRNG by all threads. Even if this data race likely does not burn down your monitor, it causes a lot of cache contention, which might explain the longer parallel running time.

Comment: Yep ok. The idea was just to test OpenMP with my config. I changed the inside of the loop with the same problem (cf edits)

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Anyway, why `shcedule(dynamic)`? Why `firstprivate(n)`?

Comment: schedule(dynamic) as I am on a Ubuntu machine -> doesn't will use the cores more efficiently ? and firstprivate(n) to copy its value to core caches -> won't it do that ? Maybe I don't use it as I should. I used OpenMP for quite a while now but only for for loops so I probably don't get don't get everything on the lib.

Comment: See my answer why you shouldn't use `schedule(dynamic)` - it does something else than you expect.

Comment: Yep I saw it ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code quickly through my system.
First of all, in the array addition case, your 50M is barely enough to show the win, but it does - if OpenMP is set up correctly.

In your case, the `schedule(dynamic)` is killing you - it tells the compiler to spread the work to the team at *runtime*. That would make sense if you cannot predetermine your workload - but in this case it's perfectly predictable as the effort per iteration is exactly the same.

I get the following results after editing your example (see below) and running on a hyperthreaded CPU with the cores all fixed on the lowest frequency. I compiled using gcc 4.9.3:

```
time ./testseq && time ./testpar

real    0m0.576s
user    0m0.504s
sys     0m0.072s

real    0m0.285s
user    0m0.968s
sys     0m0.123s
```

As you can see, the `real` value, which is the "wallclock time", roughly halves. The `user` time increases, because of thread startup and shutdown.

The parallelized results change considerably if i add the `schedule(dynamic)` clause:

```
real    0m4.181s
user    0m14.886s
sys     0m1.283s
```

All of the extra work load is spent on threads that are done doing a small amount of work and looking for the next batch. That requires taking a lock - and that kills your second example. Please only use `schedule(dynamic)` when you have load balancing issues - where the amount of work per iterator varies wildly.

To give full disclosure, I ran with the following full source code:

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -I. -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread

all: testseq testpar

testpar: test.cpp
    ${CXX} -o $@ $^ -fopenmp ${CXXFLAGS}

testseq: test.cpp
    ${CXX} -o $@ $^ ${CXXFLAGS}

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ test
```

and `test.cpp`:

```
#include <omp.h>

constexpr int n=50*1000*1000;
float a[n];
float b[n];
float c[n];

int main(void) {
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        a[i]=i;
        b[i]=i;
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    }
}
```

Note that I also took away the other clauses to your `parallel for` - you need none of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I usually  use C timers to profile my code using `clock`. And having the same speedups than you using the `time` linux command, I still have my clock difference behind bigger for the parallel code than the sequential one. Does it count all the clock ticks per core ?

Comment: Time accounting is a complex topic because many things influence the results, including frequency settings of cpu, memory bus and memory itself. I'd expect `time` and `clock(3)` to use the same accounting source - the Linux kernel. I prefer the command line for small examples like this beause it accounts for everything, including thread startup/shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` is not at all a thread-safe function. There is a PRNG inside that has a state and therefore cannot be invoked by multiple threads without synchronization. Use different PRNG (C++11 has a bunch of them, Boost as well), use one generator per thread and don't forget to seed them with **different seed values** (beware of `time(NULL)`).

**UPDATE**

`n` being 500k may be too small to get any speedup due to the overhead of thread creation. Could you test with, e.g., `n` set to 500M? Moreover, times without OpenMP are suspiciously low (maybe not for such a low `n`). What are you doing with the `a`, `b`, and `c` arrays after the loop? If nothing, a compiler could optimize the whole loop away in the sequential code. **Do something** with these arrays, e.g., print out their sum (out of the measured section).

Comment: Yep ok. The idea was just to test OpenMP with my config. I changed the inside of the loop with the same problem (cf edits)

Comment: 50M iterations will do, it's the dynamic schedule that kills OP's performance. If you write to global variables, the compiler won't optimize out `a`, `b` or `c`. With 5M iterations, there's still a gain, but it's almost down in measurement noise.